# referring local json file to axios says 404

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, axios

I am having vue 2.9.6 application wherein , I am trying to call local JSON which is placed in public/data folder, below is the syntax for the same. (considered axios is imported )

```
mounted() {

axios.post('myjson.json').then((response)=>{
           console.log(response);
})
}
```

but when I load the page, in Network, `xhr` tab it says it does not found the file. is there anything I need to do with `webpack/vue.config.js` here ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

maybe a simpler solution could work too. Also, why do you use **post** method?

```
import myjson from ' whereveritis/myjson.json'        
// and then in mounted, read the data
        data () {
        return {
          myjson: {},
        }
      },
      mounted () {
       this.myjson = myjson.data //or how do you have the structure
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

My bad, I had to use `axios.get` while working with `local JSON` and it did helped me, this might be helpful for someone.

Thanks